# InterruptedException and TaskRejectedException in SpringBootTest with Async service

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future, spring-boot-test

I am testing using `SpringBootTest`. One of the services behind uses an asynchronous service running with an Executor service that has 50 threads.

But I am getting  **Shutting Down ExecutorService asycnExecutor**, `InterruptedException` then `TaskRejectedException`  .... [shutting down pool size =8,  active thread = 8] did not accept task.
Here the threadname is  `pool-3-thread-1` and parent is `main` i assume this is from the `SpringBootTest`. Also it seems 8 tasks have been created and accepted but shutdown after that

Also no message in `InterruptedException` when I caught it specifically. message is null;

I figured the following:

- Something is shutting down the executor service when its running
- Then it goes through interrupted exception and shutsdown
- Rest of the tasks gets TaskRejectedException becuase executorservice
  shutsdown

Sample Code (tried to simplify as much as possible):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class App extends springBootServletInitializer
{
    public static voice main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(App.Class, args)
   }

   @Bean(name = "asycnExecutor")
   public Executor asycnExecutor() {
           ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exc = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
           //setcore = 50;
           //setmaxpool = 1000
           //setqueue = 2000
           //setthreadnameprefix = "customAsycn"
           //initialize
           return exc;
   }
}
```

NormalService.java

```
@Component
public class NormalService{

    @Autowired
    MyAsycnService myasyncService;

    @Cacheable("myobject")
    public MyObject someservice(){
       do_someService();
    }

    @CachePut("myobject")
     public MyObject do_someService(){
        if(many){
              /// some steps
              foreach()
              {
                CompletableFuture<myobject> blah = myasyncService.doTask();
              }
              //allof / join / .get on the list of CompletableFuture<Void> and accumulate result
         }
         else {
             ///some otherstep
             CompletableFuture<myobject> blah myasyncService.doTask();
            //just 1 result
         }
         return myObject;
     }
}
```

MyAsycnService.java

```
@Service
public class MyAsycnService {

    @Autowired
     RestTemplate restTemplate;

     @Asynch("asycnExecutor")
      public CompletableFuture<MyObject> doTask()
      {  
         ResponseEntity<string> r = restTemplate.getEntity();
         MyObject myobject = process(r);
         return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(myobject);

      }

     private MyObject process(ResponseEntity<responseEntity> r)
     {
       MyObject o = new MyObject();
       ///someprcess
      return o;
     }
}
```

ScheduledControllerCallerConfig

```
@Component
pulic class ScheduledClass {
  @Autowired
  NormalService ns;
  @Scheduled (fixedDelay = 10000, initialDelay = 500)
  public void do_something()
   {
        ns.someservice();
    } 

}
```

MyController.Java

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

 @AutoWired
  NormalService ns;

  @ApiOperation
  @RequestMapping
  public ResponseEntity<MyObject> getSomething()
  {
    MyObject = ns.someservice();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
  } 

}
```

Tests;

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT) // also tried with classes = App.class

@Autowired
TestRestTemplate restTemplate

@Mock
MyObjectmyobject

@Test
public void testResponse() {

}
```

please help figure why it fails in the integration tests or some directions for debugging further?

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve] and the exact error you get?

Comment: Sure. Will update as soon as I can.